# Como definir um tamanho máximo para um campo BLOB?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, imagem, oracle11g

Estou querendo inserir imagens e quero que cada registro tenha no máximo 100M, caso esse valor seja ultrapassado deve ser retornado um erro no próprio banco.

Para exemplo de ilustração do problema: (da mesma forma que é retornado erro caso tentamos inserir uma string de 35 caracteres em uma coluna varchar(30), deve feito com a imagem maior de 100M).

Portanto se a imagem enviada for maior do que 100M o banco deve informar o erro e rejeitar o registro, vou usar a seguinte tabela como exemplo e o respectivo erro gerado:

```
CREATE TABLE imagem  
(  
  ID       NUMBER(5)  NOT NULL,  
  NOME     VARCHAR2(50),  
  IMG      BLOB(100M)  
)
```

> Error at line 1   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver seu problema, podemos colocar uma `constraint` `check`, e impor a integridade de domínio limitando os valores que são aceitos por uma coluna.

Eles são semelhantes aos `FOREIGN KEY` na medida em que controlam os valores que são colocados em uma coluna. A diferença está em como determinar quais valores são válidos, `constraint` determinam os valores válidos a partir de uma expressão lógica que não se baseia em dados de outra coluna.

No seu caso pode ser resolvido com a expressão:

```
create table imagem
(
  id   number(5),
  nome varchar2(50),
  img  clob constraint CK_IMGMAX_100 check(length(img) < 100)
);
```

Ou seja, criamos uma `constraint` para a coluna de imagem chamada, `CK_IMGMAX_100` e checando se o tamanho da imagem é menor que 100, assim
a coluna só permite que seja adicionados valores menores que 100 mb.

Outro caso interessante de se utilizar, em um exemplo mais habitual, 
é checar o tamanho do nome da pessoa, exemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE imagem
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_IMAGEM
CHECK ( length(nome) BETWEEN 3 AND 50 );
```

Assim o campo `nome` somente recebera valores entre 5 e 50 caracteres.

Comment: Testei aqui e deu certo, obrigado!

Comment: Eu ja tinha tentado de uma forma semelhante seguindo o tutorial do link: http://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/Setting-maximum-size-of-a-blob-data-type,8

Comment: Mas se puder explicar mais detalhado para um melhor entendimento eu agradeço.

Comment: Adicionei uma melhor explicação para a solução do problema ;)

Comment: Obrigado @David!

Comment: @HarissonFordA.R., você poderia marcar como resolvido? No lado esquerdo tem um simbolo de ✓, clique. Assim indicara que essa é a resposta para sua pergunta. Obrigado